# How to write a formula or code for matching cell values in excel (if Sheet1 a2 = sheet2 c column then insert value for S in same row)

Tags: excel, typescript, excel-formula, scripting, typescript-typings

I need to write either a script in excel or formula if possible to do the following:

Project number is stored in Sheet1 in column A and sheet2 in Column C respectively (these sheets aren't in the same order)

If the the value for A2 in sheet1 matches the value of any anything in Column C of sheet2, I need to fill the cell with the value S (sheet2) in whatever row where C (sheet2) = A2. Adding This will continue for A3, A4,etc.

There may be duplicates I am fine with it taking the first value (it should be right).

Note the value is text

Basically we track projects by PMs at work and the pms never change, but each department tracks things differently and in different order. My sheet needs to take values from multiple sheets all based on PM numbers which are stored in the same row on their given sheets. I know python but not typescript for context

Comment: Looks to me like you need INDEX-MATCH but it's difficult to decypher. It would be a lot easier if you just showed us what your data looks like and what the expected output looks like. You can post a screenshot of the sheets or better yet, make it a markdown table. You can use this generator: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: You can use [VLOOKUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP worksheet function can do this for you on single ranges and return first hit. And you can combine it with IF, COUNTIF and so on to do several lookups and tests.

Or if you save your Excel book as .xlsm (Macro enabled workbook), you can make your own functions in Excel a VBA module. Alt+F11 will open your projects explorer where you can type your Visual Basic code.

Here is a simple Function. By adding =GetProjektNumber(and pointing to the cell with reference to ProjektNumber). This formula can be dragged and dropped in the sheet. It will look for the value in column C in all sheets and return the value in column S (=19 in Cells reference)

```
Function GetProjektNumber(MyCellReferance As Range) As String
GetProjektNumber = "# Not found"
For Each sh In Worksheets
With Worksheets(sh.Name).Range("C1:C" & Trim(Worksheets(sh.Name).UsedRange.Rows.Count))
Set c = .Find(MyCellReferance.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    GetProjektNumber = Worksheets(sh.Name).Cells(c.Row, 19)
End If
End With
Next
End Function
```